# How to pass number and message inbuild messaging in Android emulator?

Tags: android, messaging

I am working on a Android application. In this application I am connect inbuild messaging. In this messaging, statically pass the number and text in my app.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please read through your question again and correct the mistakes. Using punctuation marks also would greatly improve the readability of your question.

Comment: can you elaborate why you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String number = "12345678";
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
            Uri.fromParts("sms", phone_number, null));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank u very much for valuable response

Comment: Welcome, But next time please clarify your question if possible with some code,image or stack trace then other user can also help you. Thanks.